# Getting 404 error when deploying static html, css and js files into the vercel

Tags: html, deployment, static, http-status-code-404, vercel

I am getting 404 error when deploying on vercel with static html, css and JS files. It is getting deployed perfectly within 3 seconds. The error page:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRMLl.png)

I am expecting it to show webpage but it is showing 404. it just contains one html file and one css file with a single image

Comment: please provide the [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and error in text form.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer. Just make sure that the html file name is index.html. Its a silly mistake but causes error